# CMAKE : Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root on windows 10

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

I am using cmake to compile a c++ github project on windows10. Getting the following error,

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/techn/cmake-3.22.1-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/techn/cmake-3.22.1-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Users/techn/cmake-3.22.1-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:574 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  deps/libsrtp/CMakeLists.txt:75 (find_package)
```

But Openssl is installed and environment variables are set and verified on cmd as shown below

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\techn>openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021

C:\Users\techn>
```

Comment: have you set `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`? Does your open ssl directory contain the libraries or just the executable?

Comment: OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR is set. Open ssl directory contains only the executable.

Comment: you can't build against an executable, you need the library files and header files

Comment: git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git, done. Now open ssl directory contain  both the libraries and executable. Still getting the same error.

Comment: did you build the openssl source code or just check it out?